# Angular Push Notification get received several times

Tags: angular, push-notification, notifications, push

i have followed the documentation by Angular to make push notification working:
https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-push-notifications/

My problem is now that every time my side gets reloaded, or if i open up the PWA installation on desktop, then a new Push Subscription object gets written in my database.

If one client loads the side 5 times, i get 5 Times the same notification for this client. Since i have 5 Subscription Objects in my database. That is not what i want. The client should get a notification once and not for each stored object in the database.

Inside Angular i cant find any place, where the subscribe for push whould only be executed once.

How can this be archived? Any help would be highly appreciate.

In my app.module.ts i do:

```
     export class AppModule {
        constructor(update: SwUpdate, push: SwPush,
        pushToServer:SubscribeNotificationService ) {

        push.requestSubscription({
             serverPublicKey: environment.VAPID_PUBLIC_KEY
        })
        .then(pushSubscription => {
             console.log(typeof(pushSubscription));
             console.log(pushSubscription.toJSON());
             console.log("call addPushSubscriber");
         pushToServer.addPushSubscriber(pushSubscription).then(res =>   
         console.log("res: " + res));
       })
       .catch(err => {console.log(err);});
```

The corresponding SubscribeNotificationService looks like this:

```
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
    import { environment } from '../../environments/environments';

     @Injectable({
      providedIn: 'root'
     })
     export class SubscribeNotificationService {

     readonly VAPID_PUBLIC_KEY = environment.VAPID_PUBLIC_KEY;

     constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

     addPushSubscriber(subscription : any) { // [object PushSubscription]
     return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          this.http.post(environment.PUSHNOTIFICATION_API, subscription)
          .subscribe({
          next: (data) => resolve(data),
          error: (err) => reject(err)
          });
       })

     }
  }
```